# Is there a way to "shape" CSS button outline according to button shape?

Tags: css

Is it possible to shape the outline that appears when a CSS button is clicked? When clicking a rounded button the outline just looks a bit *off*.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style media="screen">
    .button {
      border-radius: 80%;
      padding: 16px 32px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="button">BUTTON</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nop, but you can reset outline and use a box-shadow

Comment: Are you looking for any particular answer other than the outline css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of the existing border when the button comes into focus (or is active) - and you also have the option of changing its color or style (ridge etc) as you wish.

```css
.button:focus, .button:active {
    outline-style:none;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
} 
        .button {
          border-radius: 80%;
          padding: 16px 32px;
        }
```

```html
      <button class="button">BUTTON</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

override outline behavior on the focus of the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style media="screen">
    .button {
      border-radius: 80%;
      padding: 16px 32px;
    }
    .button:focus {
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 7px 0px #888888;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="button">BUTTON</button>
</body>

</html>
```